# How to get program to access data file to output average score and highest scorer with suggested class data? How to alleviate error in Button 1 click?

Tags: c#, average, streamreader, streamwriter

I am tasked to write a program that accesses an outside text file that contains basketball player names and scores. I have always had issues reading and writing from txt files regardless of language. Once the txt file is read from, the program is supposed to output the average scores for all players as well as the player name of the highest scorer. Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace TextFiles
{
public partial class BasketBallStats : Form
{
    List<int> marks = new List<int>();

    public BasketBallStats()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Form load event handler used to construct
    // object of the Streamwriter class, sending the 
    // new filename as an argument. Enclosed in
    // try...catch block.
    public class BasketballController
    {
        public class Entry
        {
            public int Value { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        BasketballController(string filename)
        {
            this.filename = filename;
        }
        private string filename;
        private List<Entry> data = new List<Entry>();
        public List<Entry> Data
        {
            get
            {
                // Clear data
                data.Clear();
                // Iterate through lines
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
                {
                    // Split by space
                    List<string> parts = line.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
                    if (parts.Count() < 2)
                        continue;
                    // Number is last space separated string
                    int number = int.Parse(parts.Last());
                    // Remove number
                    parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count() - 1);
                    // Name is any previous word joined by space
                    string name = string.Join(" ", parts).Trim();

                    // Add number and name to data
                    data.Add(new Entry() { Name = name, Value = number });
                }
                // Sort from greater value to smaller
                data.Sort(Comparer<Entry>.Create(
                    (l, r) => r.Value.CompareTo(l.Value)));
                return data;
            }
            set
            {
                using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
                {
                    foreach (var entry in value)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", entry.Name, entry.Value));
                    }
                }
                data = value;
            }
        }
        public double Average
        {
            get
            {
                // Read file if data is empty, otherwise reuse its value
                var src = (data.Count() == 0) ? Data : data;
                if (src.Count() == 0)
                    return 0.0;
                // Return average
                return src.Average(x => x.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    private string score;

    public List<int> Marks { get => Marks1; set => Marks1 = value; }
    public List<int> Marks1 { get => marks; set => marks = value; }

    private void BasketBallStats_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void BtnCreateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        score = "basketBallScore.txt";
        if (File.Exists(score))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileName: {0}", score);
            Console.WriteLine("Attributes: {0}",
                File.GetAttributes(score));
            Console.WriteLine("Created: {0}",
                File.GetCreationTime(score));
            Console.WriteLine("Last Accessed: {0}",
                File.GetLastAccessTime(score));

            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(".");
            Console.WriteLine("Current Directory: \n{0} \n",
                Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            Console.WriteLine("File Name".PadRight(52) +
                "Size".PadRight(10) + "Creation Time");
            foreach (FileInfo fil in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
            {
                string name = fil.Name;
                long size = fil.Length;
                DateTime creationTime = fil.CreationTime;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1,12:NO} {2, 20:g} ", name.PadRight(45),
                    size, creationTime);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} not found - using current" +
                "directory:", score);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private void BtnWriteFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var WriteToFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("basketBallScore.txt"); //create textfile in default directory
            WriteToFile.Write(listView1.Text + ", " + listView1.Text + ", " + listView1.Text + ", " + listView1.Text);
            WriteToFile.Close();
            Marks.Add(Convert.ToInt32(listView1.Text)); //add to list
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "File did not close properly: ";    //add error message
        }
    }

    private void ManipulateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] hoursArray = new int[30];
        StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader("basketBallScore.txt");
        int counter = 0;
        string line = "";
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            hoursArray[counter] = int.Parse(line);
            counter = counter + 1;
            line = fileSR.ReadLine();
        }
        fileSR.Close();

        int total = 0;
        double average = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
        {
            total = total + hoursArray[index];
        }
        average = (double)total / hoursArray.Length;

        int high = hoursArray[0];
        for (int index = 1; index < hoursArray.Length; index++)
        {
            if (hoursArray[index] > high)
            {
                high = hoursArray[index];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Highest number is: " + high);
        Console.WriteLine("The average is: " + average);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void BasketBallStats_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void CalcAverage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int totalmarks = 0;
        foreach (int m in Marks)
            totalmarks += m;

        MessageBox.Show("Average Is: " + totalmarks / Marks.Count);
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var c = new BasketballController("basketBallScore.txt");
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Average {0}", c.Average));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("First {0} {1}", c.Data.First().Name, c.Data.First().Value));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Last {0} {1}", c.Data.Last().Name, c.Data.Last().Value));
    }
  }
}
```

This is what the text file contains:

```
Lebron James        31
Steph Curry         12
Kyrie Irving        37
Kevin Durant        9
Paul George         35
Klay Thompson       8
J.R.Smith           12  
Zaza Pachulia       4
Tristan Thompson    10
Draymond Green      2
```

The program will access the file but will not give any output beyond the verification of the the data file.

Comment: What specifically is your question?

Comment: I have no idea what the code is doing wrong. It is not outputting any information, so how do I get the code to out put information? How do I get it to give the correct output info? Why is it not saving the the file correctly? Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Does the file get created or not? If it gets created, is it empty (i.e. zero length)? Does the file get created but does not contain what you expect? (If so, what does it actually contain?)

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

- When you see the name of the file twice in your code (and it's actually 4 times), you have a problem waiting to happen. Replace all those texts with a class member.
- Usually when working with text files, you don't keep them open, you follow this pattern:

  - Open file in read-only mode
  - Read data
  - Close file
  - Do something with data
  - Open file in write mode
  - Write data (overwriting previous file)
  - Close file
    And wait as little as possible between Open and Close operations. However you make them.

The main issue with your code is when your form gets loaded:

```
private void Form1_Load(object seneder, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        filbasketBallStat = new StreamWriter("basketBallScore.txt");
```

If you check the MSDN for the [StreamWriter(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor, you'll read following:

> If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

So when this is run, your file should end up being blank, therefore there is nothing to read and nothing to report.

You should also probably abstract the functionality away from the Form. That will give you more flexibility and allow you to debug easier.

This should work:

```
class BasketballController
{
    public class Entry
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    BasketballController(string filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    private string filename;
    private List<Entry> data = new List<Entry>();
    public List<Entry> Data
    {
        get
        {
            // Clear data
            data.Clear();
            // Iterate through lines
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
            {
                // Split by space
                List<string> parts = line.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
                if (parts.Count() < 2)
                    continue;
                // Number is last space separated string
                int number = int.Parse(parts.Last());
                // Remove number
                parts.RemoveAt(parts.Count() - 1);
                // Name is any previous word joined by space
                string name = string.Join(" ", parts).Trim();

                // Add number and name to data
                data.Add(new Entry() { Name = name, Value = number });
            }
            // Sort from greater value to smaller
            data.Sort(Comparer<Entry>.Create(
                (l, r) => r.Value.CompareTo(l.Value)));
            return data;
        }
        set
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                foreach (var entry in value)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", entry.Name, entry.Value));
                }
            }
            data = value;
        }
    }
    public double Average
    {
        get
        {
            // Read file if data is empty, otherwise reuse its value
            var src = (data.Count() == 0) ? Data : data;
            if (src.Count() == 0)
                return 0.0;
            // Return average
            return src.Average(x => x.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how any file-handling code is together and how it gets closed after opening as soon as possible.

You can use the class like this:

```
var c = new BasketballController("basketBallScore.txt");
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Average {0}", c.Average));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("First {0} {1}", c.Data.First().Name, c.Data.First().Value));
Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Last {0} {1}", c.Data.Last().Name, c.Data.Last().Value));
```

Which outputs:

```
Average 16
First Kyrie Irving 37
Last Draymond Green 2
```

Comment: So this should be assigned to the form load button then? And assign the debug.writeline statements at the end of the buttons.

Comment: No, `Debug.WriteLine` is just a way of seeing the value of the variables. The interesting parts are that you assign a `BasketballController` instance to a variable (e.g. `c`) and then you can just use `c.Average` and `c.Data.First()` to access average and the player with most "points".
You are free to do with that as you will, e.g. integrating with your GUI logic which is hard to follow without the actual form.

Comment: I really appreciate your clarification. But I am assuming this class should be within the body of the code then I can integrate the debug.writeline statements to possibly a BtnCalculate_click button for instance.

Comment: Forget about `Debug.WriteLine`, it's a thing that helps when debugging, see  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz(v=vs.110).aspx
The class is just something you add to your project, you can do that in any way you want. Either by adding it in its own `.cs` file to the project, or adding it to your `.cs` file containing your form *outside* your class or *inside* your class. The one thing you cannot do is put it inside a method.

Comment: So then I should disregard those statements? Just write the statements like so?                                                   
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Average {0}", c.Average));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("First {0} {1}", c.Data.First().Name, c.Data.First().Value));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Last {0} {1}", c.Data.Last().Name, c.Data.Last().Value));

Answer (score -1):

Try following code for reading file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Player(FILENAME);

        }

    }
    public class Player
    {
        const int NAME_COL_WIDTH = 20;

        public static List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

        public string name { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }

        public Player() { } //player constructor with no parameters
        public Player(string filename)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            string inputLine = "";
            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Player newPlayer = new Player();
                players.Add(newPlayer);

                newPlayer.name = inputLine.Substring(0, NAME_COL_WIDTH).Trim();
                newPlayer.score = int.Parse(inputLine.Substring(NAME_COL_WIDTH));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```